# When a burninate request is approved, who should do the burnination?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

This is related to [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934) but I didn't find an answer to my question there.

If a burnination request is approved, who should do the burnination? Should that be some sort of a privillege to the user who requested the burnination, or could it be done by anyone from the community?

Comment: It can be done by anyone from the community. The goal is to a) gather feedback, and b) organise a burning party of willing members to go out and take care of the tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for an answer. Is it approppriate to add it to the wiki post mentioned above?

Comment: If you feel you can improve on the post, by all means edit it.