# What to do about [teamcity-*] and [resharper-*]?

Tags: discussion, support

There is a versioned tag for each minor release of JetBrains' TeamCity: [teamcity-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity-8.0), [teamcity-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity-8.1), etc. (There is also [teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity).) There is a similar situation with JetBrains' [resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper).

Some questions are tagged only with the version tag and not the non-versioned tag. I follow [teamcity*], so I'll probably see new questions regardless, but that doesn't help when I click on a tag or do a search with booleans. I would like to discourage use of the version-specific tags and encourage use of the versionless tags. [The MSE discussion of version-specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags) concurs.

I also think that there is no need for a tag for each minor version. A tag for major version would probably suffice for the handful of questions that I've seen that actually seem to be related to version differences. I would like to discourage creation of new tags for new minor versions.

I think the right thing to do is

- put comments at the top of the minor-version tag wiki entries indicating that those tags should not be used (since it will take a while to go through them and we want to stop the bleeding)
- read every question with a minor-version tag and

  - add the versionless tag if the question doesn't already have it
  - add the appropriate major-version tag if the question justifies it (creating it the first time it's needed)
  - remove the minor-version tag
- wait for the orphaned minor-version tags to disappear

Yes? No? Better ideas?

Comment: A lot of what I was asking is in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proposed steps are good.
This is not something that needs major consensus though - simply retagging as appropriate will take care of the problem. When tags are no longer used then they will automatically be pruned. It seems that quite often the version specific tags are used because it feels right (rather than being necessary), and users are unsure exactly what they should be tagging with.

Keep in mind that you will have to also add some tags, questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23886008/109702) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24083389/109702) which are simply tagged with [teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity) [teamcity-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity-8.1) will need another tag added when you remove [teamcity-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity-8.1).

Comment: About adding tags, agreed, that's bullet 4. The main thing that seemed iffy to me was deprecating tags in their wiki entries. If no-one else pops up and says "no, do it this way" I'll do that deprecation soon.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Yeah I haven't checked all the tag wikis (but I notice 8.1 had no wiki). I don't know for sure what happens to the wikis of tags that are pruned, even if they're not auto pruned they should be easy enough to remove. I would suggest that you might not have to alter some wikis if they disappear along with their tag (i.e. you might not have to 'deprecate' it, just do the retag).

Comment: By experiment, tags don't go away even if no question is tagged with them -- [tag:teamcity-4.0] for example.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth That's not the right way to test for the existence of tags - i.e. I get the same result if I search for [teamcity-3.1415926](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity-3.1415926) - the only difference is mine doesn't have a wiki entry. The tags are cleaned up by a batch script that runs periodically so you won't see it disappear instantly. Try using `teamcity-4.0` in another 24 hours time and see if it still exists.

Comment: The actual test I used was that when I search for [teamcity*] I'm redirected to [teamcity] or [teamcity-7.0] or [teamcity-8.0] or [teamcity-7.1] or [teamcity-6.5] or [teamcity-6.0] or [teamcity-5.1] or [teamcity-5.0] or [teamcity-6] or [teamcity-4] or [teamcity-8.1] or [teamcity-4.0]. I think there have been no questions tagged [teamcity-8.1] for more than 24 hours. But there's no rush; I'll wait and see.

Comment: The tags I orphaned are gone now.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Cool - the wiki entries are gone too.