# Burninate [slave]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) (100+ Questions) does not even have a single Follower :)

Comment: Is [master] any better? Should [master][slave] questions be retagged [master-slave] rather than just removing [slave]?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have down voted your suggestion - for now.

Have you done a pass through the questions and done a tidy up, fixed the questions that are just mistagged because the OP had no clue? Have you really determined that the tag is incorrect and/or useless on [*XC8 pic16f876a I2C slave*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23183981/109702) and [*Sending data from Slave to Master over SPI with ioctl() Linux*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23006768/109702) or [*Setting up a slave with Solr 4.3.1*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17711415/109702)? (Note that these are rhetorical samples from the list, there are also other problems with some of these aside from the tags).

[Requesting a burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/109702) involves more than just checking how many followers a tag has. You need to *show* that a tag can be removed, not just *suggest* it.

Of course once a clean up has been done then I will be all for it.