# Should [slave] be removed from [jenkins] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 39 [questions tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jenkins]%20[slave]%20is%3Aq), but there are 506 [questions tagged with [jenkins] and mentioning 'slave', but without the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jenkins]+slave+is%3Aq+-[slave]). That makes me wonder which way to go:

- Remove [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) from the 39 questions, or
- Add [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) to the 506 questions

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262953)

Comment: Should [c++] be removed from [7,000 \[stl\] questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstl%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aq) or should it be added to the 357 questions that are tagged [stl] but not [c++]? Bearing in mind the [stl] tag is described *specifically* as "a C++ library".

Comment: All STL Questions are C++ Questions, so I think [tag:c++] should be added to those 357 [tag:stl] Questions.

Comment: But if all STL questions are C++ questions **per their own definition**, surely the tag [c++] is redundant? I'm trying to find out if you are attempting to clean up tags or making a covert socio-political statement. [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262953/burninate-slave).

Comment: General practice is to include the greater tag even if the more specific tag implies it (e.g. [python] on [python-3.x] Questions).

Comment: Regardless, these are separate issues: [jenkins] and [slave] are not necessarily related to each other, unlike [c++] and [stl].

Answer (score 2):

Now there is also [jenkins-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-slave) with 168 questions, which is an appropriate tag for this.

So **yes**, I think it makes sense to remove [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) from Jenkins questions and replace it with [jenkins-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-slave).

Note: the term "slave" was renamed to "agent" in Jenkins terminology some time ago, take a look at [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364592/make-jenkins-slave-a-synonym-for-jenkins-agent) also.