# Make [jenkins-slave] a synonym for [jenkins-agent]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Term "slave" was renamed to "agent" in Jenkins a while ago:

- See [this resolved issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27268)
- See [another issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33369)
- Also [this merged pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/2007)
- [This guide](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) now also refers to "agents"

I think it makes sense to create [jenkins-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-agent) and make [jenkins-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-slave) a synonym for it.
It's better than renaming a tag, since there are old questions mentioning "Jenkins slaves".

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265537/should-slave-be-removed-from-jenkins-questions?rq=1

Comment: What does it take to get this actioned to make [jenkins-slave] a synonym for [jenkins-agent], or even better, replace [jenkins-slave] with [jenkins-agent] and drop the [jenkins-slave] tag ? Is that "Burninate" it?

Comment: @IanW I think this should be a "retag-request"