# Can we burninate [java-libraries]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [java-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-libraries) has 230 associated questions, but seems pretty meta to me. Can we burninate this?

There is no tag wiki to explain what is meant by this nebulous tag. So I can only assume it applies to questions where some kind of Java library is used. Pretty useless, IMO.

Comment: Shouldn't you first clean up single-tag questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771284/how-do-i-run-this-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765005/whats-wrong-with-easy-java-persistence)? What will you do for the questions that will be single-tagged *after* a clean up?

Comment: @slugster Yes, that seems like a reasonable first step that I omitted. I'll have a dig about.

Comment: @slugster Actually, those were the only two questions. I [edited this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771284/how-do-i-run-this-file), not sure what to do about [the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765005/whats-wrong-with-easy-java-persistence). I've voted to close because it's generally awful.

Comment: Cool, [it's appropriate to do a pass through and clean up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/109702) as part of a burnination request.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I propose that we synonymize the tag into [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) instead. While a burnination may be effective for this, the tag is essentially a meta tag for Java and having `[java-libraries]` as its synonym will prevent users from re-creating the tag, as well as be self-documenting that questions that asks related to Java libraries should just use the `[java]` tag.
And saves us some time and work going through the posts as well.

I went ahead and proposed [the tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms), which has since been approved.