# What to do with the [trap] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap) seems to be used in a few different ways. This list is in approximate order of occurrence, however none of them is obviously dominant over the others.

1. Shell scripting / Bash related. "trap" is a keyword in Bash. Example: [cp: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281942/cp-command-not-found)
2. SNMP traps. Generally questions about SNMP communications, where a trap is a kind of notification message. Example: [snmp trap specific trap code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376381/snmp-trap-specific-trap-code)
3. Systems programming in C or ASM, "trap frames" for exception handling: [Motorola 68K TRAP instruction as a bridge to OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455305/motorola-68k-trap-instruction-as-a-bridge-to-os)
4. Various other languages where "trap" is a keyword (Powershell etc)
5. Seemingly at random, like [How to trap negative integer inputs in C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519025/how-to-trap-negative-integer-inputs-in-c-program) or [Trapping mouse on one monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186946/trapping-mouse-on-one-monitor)

It could be argued that these disparate uses, taken together, indicate that the tag has "no clearly defined meaning" in accordance with the rules from the FAQ 
[How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

There are currently 250 questions tagged [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap). They all seem to also be tagged with some more useful tag, like [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) or [snmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snmp).

So, perhaps [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap) ought to be burninated? It seems to only cause confusion since it can't reliably be used to search for questions on a particular topic. 
On the other hand, in the first four uses listed at least, the "trap" term used in a valid way in the question, and I can see how it made sense to the poster to add the tag in the first place.

If I start re-tagging, should I re-tag the SNMP questions as [snmptrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snmptrap)? It's a common enough term that it might warrant its own tag, but the tag doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: Why, when the problem is that a tag has at least 4 different legitimate meanings, is your first thought to *burninate* it? Although perhaps retagging some of those questions might be in order…

Comment: Someone somewhere is now hearing Admiral Ackbar saying "It's a trap!" in their heads. That person is probably you now. You're welcome. (Some of these probably need to be retagged, then see what's left before deciding if we should burninate it completely)

Comment: It's probably better to disambiguate the first four uses of the tag by adding more specific tag, then burn the rest.

Comment: 1 and 4 are the same use.  Case 5 can just be untagged.

Comment: To clarify, this is not a burninate request, but a discussion post. I should never have used the word...

Comment: Another meaning: trap representation, mainly relevant to C and C++, meaning that a variable has a value that cannot be represented for that type. And as for trap in Motorola 68k, the same nomenclature lives on in other Freescale/Motorola parts, where a "trap procedure" simply means an interrupt service routine.

Comment: Yes, it should be removed. Suppose you are an expert in "trap" (gold badge), what does it tell others ? Nothing. Just another useless piece of information about you.

Comment: Title suggestion: Should we [trap] this tag?

Comment: I'd suggest that yes, an [snmp-trap] tag would be appropriate (but with a hyphen to match [bash-trap]). Also, since shell traps are not (AFAIK!) shell-specific, perhaps [bash-trap] should be replaced with [sh-trap]?

Comment: ...or possibly [posix-trap], since [POSIX specifies how `trap` works](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/trap.html)?

Comment: Also, re: [snmp-trap], there seem to be [lots of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=snmp+trap+-%5Btrap%5D) for which such a tag may be appropriate but which are not already tagged [trap].

Comment: I am amused, this entire topic has become a trap itself. Burninate:yes has been downvoted.  Burninate:no has been downvoted. Dear god, meta has *gone meta.*

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, let's burninate it.

Removed the [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trap) tag from all questions.

- Bash `keyword` questions re-tagged with [bash-trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-trap) (and [signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals) when applicable)
- Other unix Shell questions using `trap` keyword re-tagged with [shell-trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-trap) (and [signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals) when applicable)
- Ruby `trap` keyword questions re-tagged with [exception-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling).
- Powershell `trap` keyword questions re-tagged with [powershell-trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-trap).
- Questions related to "trap abort" errors in C/C++ programming were mostly related to off-by-one errors or other errors in memory management. Re-tagged them as [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) or [off-by-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/off-by-one) as applicable.
- A few completely irrelevant usages were simply removed.

Comment: [tag:trap] is now a synonym for [tag:bash-trap] and no one seems to have objected to it yet. No one actually used [tag:shell-trap] and [tag:powershell-trap] since 2017 (I edited two questions today that have both [tag:powershell] and [tag:bash-trap], and that's all). I guess [tag:snmp-trap] is still relevant but I don't think it's unnecessary to have a separate tag for that. What was the point of all this?

Comment: The point was elaborated in the comments on the Question, above. Personally, I like to be able to find snmp-trap related questions/answers without finding mostly bash questions intermigled. Tags that mean multiple distinct things are useless and need to be disambiguated.

Answer (score -8):

OK, since no-one else is doing it, I'll try to answer this based on my own opinion and that of commenters.

No, let's not burninate the tag. Instead, I'll go through the tagged questions ilke the following:

- Bash, scripting and SNMP questions get to keep the tag, if it's relevant to the question. Re-tag if there is a more specific relevant tag. Likewise for systems programming questions. This covers cases 1, 2, 3 and 4.
- Remove the tag in case 5.

Assuming, of course, this answer is voted up.

Comment: I disagree with keeping this tag. 1, 2, 3 and 4 are all different entities. You can be an expert in one, and be a noob in another. I suggest they should be renamed to "bash-trap", "motorola-trap" etc. Remember, gold badge bearers have a closing super power.

Comment: I'm open to such action. I don't know that we can form a consensus of 2 users, but maybe post an alternative Answer here and drum up some votes for it?

Comment: I started implementing Neolisk's suggestion, but now I have too many pending edits (after editing 5 questions). If anyone with a gold badge could help, this would go much quicker...

Comment: I've come here from the edit review queue. Can I ask that if you are going to re-tag these questions, you also deal with everything else that needs attending to at the same time (spelling, grammar etc.), please.

Comment: Not sure that's a fair ask, given the quality of some questions, and the sheer volume... I'll try though!

Comment: OK, but *someone* will have to address the other stuff in the edit review if you don't. You are likely to get your edits rejected if there are many other issues which are not addressed. I just improved one of yours, but I've now run out of edits...

Comment: @Jolta, please actually read [the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/215552) in that question you posted, namely the following text: *Additionally, if you have below 2000 reputation, it's especially important to fix all other issues with a post, as there's some work involved in actually getting your edit approved, and it may get rejected if it doesn't fix all issues.*

Comment: Hi @MikeMcCaughan I have indeed been trying to follow that rule in my edits subsequent to the reminder from SiHa above. Let me know if you see me mess up any particular edit.

Comment: I rejected https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15507757 : the tag excerpt is about ASM and the question too. Please successfully edit the excerpt to be Bash/SNMP-related before attempting to retag the ASM questions.

Comment: @Cœur not sure I understood your comment. The tag exerpt for [trap] mentions specifically the LC-3 assembly language, but the plan is to remove that tag once it's gone from all questions. My edit was to replace [trap] with [assembly-trap]. Should it be a different tag, in your opinion?

Comment: change the excerpt to "DO NOT USE" before retagging. And with a balance of +4 votes and -3 votes on your answer, it's not a very popular change you're doing here. And because you have less than 2000 reputation, it's a slow process that makes the usage of the tag inconsistent during the process.

Comment: I've approved your tag change.

Comment: Since this answer was unpopular, I posted a new answer with the actions I actually took.