# Burninate [failed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Just today, a new [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failed) tag has appeared. It has two questions so far, and I suspect it's going to quickly collect a lot of questions about code that doesn't work. I don't see how it can ever be useful to categorize any questions. Can we burninate it before it gets out of control?

Comment: Oh no; we failed to burninate it? ;-) I've deleted it from those two. If we just watch it for a bit, it should go away.

Comment: Totally agree, that tag isn't of any good.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is that all it takes to burninate a tag? [This MSO answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/2615940) specifically says that anyone can burninate a tag, but it doesn't really say how to do it. If I see something like that again, should I just edit it out of the question and call it done?

Comment: @SLawson There is a script that runs at 03:00 UTC that removes tags that have no questions...

Comment: What @rene said :)

Comment: In such clear-cut cases, when there are no more than a handful questions, that's all it takes, just go ahead. Asking on meta is if it's either too much work alone, or it's not that clear a case.