# Burninate [pricing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I'm not sure that [pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pricing) has a purpose on this site. Seems that instead it encourages people to ask about off-topic things.

Should this be removed?

Comment: *"Pricing is spoken in terms of cost or cost involved in running or executing a particular software component."*...I would say so. Only 184 questions tagged so shouldn't take much

Comment: I'm concerned that if I edit some of these questions, the reviewer will decline the edit.  I'm considerably new to this site, is there a better solution?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934

Comment: @codeMagic Ah, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: +1; that tag needs burnination. And this post could well be turned into a burninate-request.

Comment: Edited the tags, thanks for the suggestion @S.L.Barth

Comment: examples of how burninatation requests work http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=burninate

Comment: @codeMagic It's amazing how I managed to not know about this until now.

Comment: We all start ignorant, and only learn over time *how* ignorant.

Comment: Amazing indeed ;) But, seriously, there is quite a bit to the SE network so it just takes time, curiosity, and browsing to learn how it all works. Someday even I might understand it

Comment: Title looks like *pricing* for burninations:)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Burninated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pricing) [pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pricing)!

[image: DIS HAZ BIN BURNINATED]