# disambiguate [dataprovider] for testng

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There have already been several disambig's on [dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataprovider). I'm proposing another one.

The new tag is probably best called [testng-dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testng-dataprovider). This will refer to `@DataProvider`, a TestNG annotation that allows combinations of parameters (test data) to be automatically injected into your test methods. It's encountered often with Selenium.

Numerous posts (scores of them) tagged [dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataprovider) do not refer to "Flex DataGrid and AdvancedDataGrid", which are part of the current [dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataprovider) tag description. Any question with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testng) would need to be moved to the new tag. I can go ahead and submit edits for the relevant ones.

Here are 3 pending edits for relevant posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495727/in-testng-how-to-prevent-data-provider-from-logging-to-the-result-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521712/how-to-pass-multiple-user-accounts-in-selenium-using-testng-data-provider
- [How do i use dataprovider with apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720552/how-do-i-use-dataprovider-with-apache-poi)

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Now that I am over 2k rep and since 3 folks upvoted Aify's answer, I've finished the retags for [tag:testng-dataprovider]. However, there are still a few ambiguities in [tag:dataprovider] between the .net and php meanings of this tag.

Answer (score 3):

I'm all for disambiguation, but I've seen and rejected many of your edits this morning already.

If you're going to fix the tags of a question, fix the entire question while you're at it.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8381288 doesn't even have java code - in fact, the question barely suggests anything related to java other than the tag and annotations (which could really be in a multitude of languages). (That's a bad example though, since it was a horribly low quality question to begin with, but I hope you get my point)

Furthermore, you've started the retagging of this with no community support or discussion. While I can't find anything saying it's prohibited to do so, submitting tons of tag edits (and just tag edits) is annoying for reviewers to deal with. Not only have I rejected many of them for "no improvement whatsoever", I had to reject one of them for "irrelevant tags" because you ADDED an incorrect tag.

Finally, you should read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/4446875 and stop retagging until you at least get some upvotes on this question.

Googling Flex DataGrid and AdvancedDataGrid instantly brings up ActionScript 3 - judging by the amount of mistagged questions, I agree that this could be a good retag and I agree with the disambiguation between the current tags and a [testng-dataprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testng-dataprovider) tag, but please, lay off on the edits, at least for now.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your comments. I wasn't aware of a protocol for retags, this is great to know.

Comment: @Barett No problem - Always great to have people that are willing to learn! But yea, the protocol is detailed in the above linked answer.