# Stop the [manipulation]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manipulation) currently has over <s>700</s> 0 questions. Its excerpt:

> Manipulation is the act of algorithmically manipulating any pieces of data

...is ambiguous and not helpful, in my opinion.

---

Interestingly, questions that have this tag are often trying to spell *something manipulation*.

Feed the roomba by downvoting useless questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmanipulation%5D+answers%3A0+score%3A0..

[manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manipulation) adds little information to the questions. Request to burninate the tag.

---

**Note**: I noticed from the Suggested Edits review queue that, someone keeps editing questions (over a hundred) to remove [manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manipulation) but never fixes other problems in these questions, please improve the questions with all the problems, questions with ambiguous tag often have a below average quality.

Comment: I concur. How does one go about burniating? Is there a question or wiki post about how to go about it?

Comment: handled manipulation with date/time/datetime. [tag:date-math] and [tag:date-manipulation] should probably be merged or synonymized. Link for feeding the roomba (only downvote questions deserving it please): <http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmanipulation%5d%20answers%3a0%20score%3a0..>

Comment: I've just killed [tag:tag-manipulation], [tag:table-manipulation] and [tag:jquery-manipulation]. Not sure about [tag:number-manipulation]

Comment: @StuperUser [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

Comment: @Bergi: Isn't "number manipulation" just [tag:math]?

Comment: @Kevin: Rather "manipulation of something that has anything to do with numbers", judging from the tagged questions. I say burn :-)

Comment: What about [tag:pointer-manipulation] ?

Comment: In fact, since programming is defined as manipulation of a machine's state, I would vote for burnination of all "manipulation" tags (with the exception of those where there is a more specific, restricted meaning -v.g. it refers to a "manipulation" library or module, or somewhat like that-).

Comment: The word 'manipulation' is just like the word 'manager'; both are vague terms that don't add meaning.

Comment: bit-manipulation done http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=bit%20manipulation

Comment: For the sake of those of us on mobile, please put spaces between adjacent `[tag:name]`s. otherwise, it appears as just one word.

Comment: string manipulation done

Comment: ALL manipulations are done actually.

Comment: @Joze: Why are there so *many* questions left then? And anyway, if we just wanted the tag killed *without* cleaning up the questions, that would be easy, no need for any help.

Comment: @Deduplicator There were no questions yesterday, then a lot of questions came up. Am I crazy? :O) I will continue killing & cleaning up the questions.

Comment: @Joze: Up to now, you don't seem to have done *any* of the cleanup which should be done when burning a tag. *Just* killing the tag is not very useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator Many questions didn't need improvement, though admittedly I didn't check for improvements on most of them. I will do so from now on. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: This tag dosen't define anything to me, I just can't imagine a question that would ONLY refer to this tag...

Comment: You can be an expert in manipulation tho...

Comment: it may also refer to ui element manipulation, such as interactive page elements, or 3d content manipulation that doesn't appear to have a well defined tag