# Do meta "questions" need to be actual questions?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm used to post questions on Stack Overflow, so when I come here on meta I build my questions on the same format; but I often see high rated meta questions that aren't really questions (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298124/5875416)). Shall meta follow the same question and answer pattern?

Comment: That's a burninate request. The question "Can we get rid of this tag" is implied.

Comment: Meta is a good example of why SO isn't a forum.  The Q&A format doesn't really work well for it.

Comment: Why so many downvotes without an explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, [Meta works differently](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Meta is for...
>
> - ...Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
> - ...Stack Overflow users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and
> - ...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network)

The last two points are likely *not* to be questions in the grammatical sense of the word.

Answer (score 8):

[This blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/) states that they considered changing the wording:

> Kyle had some ideas about changes to the SO engine to help it [meta] adapt from the Q&A; format discussion:
>
> - wording needs to be tweaked (i.e. questions->topics, answers->replies)

---

The wording did not change, but the idea's still the same. [Meta works differently](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) than normal sites.

Answer (score 5):

No, there really isn't a compelling need to have a grammatical question.  A post making a request is fine; you could make a grammatical question out of such a request, but there's no real need to do so; you wouldn't gain anything out of such an edit.