# We have stopped doing [research]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Here is the excerpt for the [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/research) tag:

> Research is creative work undertaken on a systematic basis in order to increase the stock of knowledge, including knowledge of computer science, electrical science and communication science to devise new applications.

And the wiki:

> In Stack overflow, tag research is intended to provide guidance and direction, rather than generic solutions.
>
> There are a lot of research areas of Computer Science, Electrical Science and Communication Science. You can explore them and feel free to ask in stack overflow with tagging this keyword.

Not only is the wiki *awful* (they misspelled the site name in two different ways), but I think that it's wrong. You should not feel free to "explore them and ask in stack overflow with tagging this keyword".

This tag seems to be used for off-topic questions ("what should I research?") when it is not being used as a meta tag ("I'm a researcher" or "I'm reading some research").

Should this tag be burninated?

Comment: Also, [people who get confused about the difference between *search* and *research*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36233818/revisions).

Comment: Question score is +100/-4 at the time of featuring.

Comment: `Research is creative work undertaken on a systematic basis in order to increase the stock of knowledge, including knowledge of computer science, electrical science and communication science to devise new applications.` .... ufff... sounds broad as hell.

Comment: Question score is +180/-6 at the time of burnination initiation.

Comment: @CodyGray All pending questions were closed after request in SOCVR room, there are 0 open questions. We can move to the next phase I suppose.

Answer (score 38):

I think that this has the classic marks of a tag that should be burninated.

First off, this tag is widely abused, so its ongoing presence appears to be actively harmful. It's often being used for requests for lists of things, primarily opinion-based questions, and for requests for assistance locating off-site resources.

Secondly, it's hard to see how you can be an expert in "research" (especially research in the scope defined in the tag wiki). It's difficult to see what the tag contributes even in combination with other tags. For example, are people actually more likely to know the answer to something tagged [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/research) than they would be to know the answer to something simply tagged [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science)? How are these questions even likely to differ content-wise? This simply doesn't appear to add any meaningful information to the post, nor is it likely to help people find questions that they're likely to know the answer to.

Given that this tag is too vague to be of any use, and that it's drawing low quality questions, I say we burn it.

Comment: Cars are widely abused (at least they were on my morning commute), but removing them wouldn't improve things unless there is a plan to replace them with something better.  Also, it was a while back; but, I made all of my income doing research.  I don't know if that made me an "expert" at it, but there are professional researchers.  I'm not stating the tag should stay or go, but the supporting arguments for its removal or replacement sound very opinion oriented.

Comment: @Edwin Re: cars: transportation is a dependency of the system. The system does not depend on the [research] tag. Re: experts: It's would be far too broad of a tag if applied to the field of research in general to be useful, let alone the fact that research is not a programming topic, it's something you do _with_ programming topics. Re: opinion oriented: it may seem that way because most of the people arguing for it's removal know the criteria for tag removal, so we may neglect to reference that information on each and every mundane burnination request.

Comment: @Edwin see also: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191), [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/4639281), and [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

Answer (score 4):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This tag has been *burninated*.

[image]

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

It looks to me like this is a *classic* example of [a "meta" tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)—the *real* meaning, not the common misinterpretation of the meaning. In other words, it's a tag that describes the *nature* or *type* of question, rather than the question's *contents*.

The [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/research) tag mostly gets used on questions where the asker just happens to be doing research <sub><sup>(Example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147345/how-to-match-and-store-results-from-a-long-nested-for-loop-into-an-empty-column) is about R and statistics. It isn't *about* research; it *just so happens* that the person is using R to analyze and present their research.)</sup></sub> or thinks that the answer to their question will require research <sub><sup>(Example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913570/building-system-wide-macos-text-editing-tools) isn't actually about research. It's about macOS APIs. Sure, someone might need to do some research in order to answer it, but the *question itself* has nothing to do with research.)</sup></sub>. Neither of these are valid uses for a tag. In all such cases, the tag should just be removed. If there are other tags that need to be added to describe the *contents* of the question, then consider adding those tags while you're at it.

Other edge cases include questions like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920197/can-mendeley-work-without-downloading
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106589/do-i-have-to-create-new-software-tool-to-write-journal-paper

where the questions are actually *about* the scholarly process of academic research. Still, this is dangerously close to "meta" tag usage, and besides, the questions of this type are all very clearly off-topic for Stack Overflow. These should be closed, not retagged.

Same with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312870/how-do-you-collect-user-data-before-starting-a-web-project), which is actually about conducting research, but since that's not programming-related within Stack Overflow's scope, it should also be (and has been) closed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902783/questions-about-the-energy-function-for-seam-carving) is about a specific function related to image processing. The formula was published in a research paper, but that doesn't make the question about research. It's about that function, and related domains, such as [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) and [seam-carving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seam-carving). Same with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155832/horn-schunck-optical-flow-calculations) (note here that that one can be salvaged without closing by simply removing the off-topic recommendation-request at the end).

In [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230646/better-option-than-doevents-for-pausing-code-execution-on-main-thread), the [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/research) tag just looks like an anomaly. Obviously it should be removed, in conjunction with a general clean-up of the question's presentation (removing "EDIT", etc.)

**[research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/research) is a clearly inappropriate tag. I don't see a single question where it can be properly applied *within the scope of Stack Overflow*.** Sometimes it is a pointer to an off-topic question, and other times it's simply an irrelevant and useless tag.

Comment: Oh I thought status-completed had been burninated

Answer (score -20):

Although the abuse of this tag makes it a good candidate for removal, the spirit of the tag does have merit.

Most questions on SO are "I have this program doing blah particular thing.  It's broken, how do I fix it?"  Or "How would I implement blah in this particular setting?"  It seems like the research tag might pertain to questions about programming practices that don't necessarily have an immediate purpose.  These questions tend to get answers and comments like "Why on Earth would you need to know how to do this?"  But criticizing the asker's purpose is not constructive when the question is "Can this obscure thing be done and in what ways can it be done?"

We could use the research tag as a marker to let answerers know that the question is for purposes outside of best practices and outside of necessity.  These questions are no less valid, but they do require a slightly different take on things.  You're not looking for a solution, you're looking for an answer.

The difficulty is making askers aware of when to use the research tag.  The definition would have to be completely changed, and I don't know how tags are suggested to the askers, but it does seem a little difficult to determine when a question falls under the new definition.  I suppose key phrases such as "Out of curiosity," "Can it be done," etc., would be markers for it.

One example of what I mean is "Can you use ternary enum flags instead of binary enum flags?"

---EDIT---
As others have pointed out, this makes this a meta tag.  And therefore not a real tag.  I'm not deleting this answer (unless someone asks me to) because the comments on it have a lot of good weigh-in, and this itself, including the down votes, is a clear example of the confusion that having this tag (and others like it) can cause to less experienced users and why it should be removed.

Comment: That would make it what's known as a "Meta tag." Tags should **only** be used to describe the actual content/topic of the question (not other stuff about the question).

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: Also take a look at [this Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for details on why tags should only be used to describe the actual content of the question and why we should avoid "Meta tags."

Comment: As others have said, tags should be used only to describe the *content* of a question, never to describe its nature or purpose. The latter is known as a "meta" tag; other examples would be [homework], [beginner], [interesting], [urgent], [unanswered], etc. So the usage of [research] that you propose is right out. The only time a [research] tag would be appropriate is if you are actually asking about research, and in that sense, such a tag seems hopelessly broad.

Comment: So the question now is do I delete this answer or let it stand as a different perspective on why it should still be burned? Also, I feel like this distinction between content and purpose needs to be made more clear to users while they are asking the questions. Because until I got down voted and got these comments, that has never been made clear.  I've only seen that when taking a dip in the meta side.

Comment: I'd let it stand as a distinct opinion, personally. You don't gain or lose reputation on Meta (votes are just an expression of agreement or disagreement).

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with leaving this answer here; other people might be similarly confused. It *is* still an answer to the question, just a wrong one. :-) As far as making it more obvious when tagging, that's a pretty valid point. We don't really do a good job establishing "rules" for tagging in the tag interface itself, which is part of why we have so many bad tags being created. One of the problems is that it's pretty difficult to explain succinctly what a good tag is and what a bad tag is. It's just something you kinda have to get a feel for over time of doing it.

Comment: Arguably, that's why we should raise the reputation threshold required for the privilege to create new tags. Especially now, with SO being as well-established as it is. It's rare a new tag needs to be created, except for brand-new technologies, and we've plenty of users who would have the requisite privileges to do so when necessary. There's some guidance for what makes a good/bad tag here on Meta, but it's all far too long and complicated to even think about incorporating into the main site, and we don't even have a good place for that to go, since all tags are created on the /ask page.

Comment: @CodyGray That sounds like a great idea. Does that suggestion have a question of its own yet?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Your "meta tags considered harmful" link documented tags that detailed opinions (subjective, best-practices, beginner).  Research is typically not decided by opinion, but is decided as a task.  I'm not sure your reference supports the argument that Research should go.  As a content tag, Research is spot-on.  If it is being used to flag "do my research for me" then I think it needs cleanup, but that's the same for every tag.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I was referring to the usage of the [research] tag being proposed in this answer, which *would* be a Meta tag. If you were talking about [research] as an actual topic, that would be a different issue. It would *still* be too broad, but it wouldn't be a Meta tag *per se*.