# Improve feature request duplicate visibility

Tags: discussion

Some weeks ago I suggested this: [Change triage guidelines for “requires editing”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing), it scored 18 in less than one day.

But, after this good run, it was tagged as a duplicate of another feature request issued a year ago with 81 pts upvote ([duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance)). From this point, absolutely no attention whatsoever was given to the recent post and the feature is still not implemented even though the changes can litterally be sumed up to switching two words in a text file.

Shouldn't it be the opposite behavior? Shouldn't a duplicated feature request with high score be dealed with in priority instead of being sent below decks?

Comment: It was hardly sent "below decks"; it was linked to the higher-scored, duplicate question. Anyone seeing your question would be shown the duplicate and up vote that one, increasing its score above the 81 it already has, thus increasing its likelihood for implementation.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think you missed the point. Older questions are less likely to be up voted, as are duplicates. It's seems to be the opposite of synergistic.

Comment: @Laurel, I'm not sure I understand your point. I see that the OP is saying that they feel the newer question should be kept open. I don't see any evidence that older questions are less likely to be upvoted. I've upvoted many older questions, especially [tag:feature-request]s. Adding more duplicates hardly seems the right thing to do. If the staff are going to implement something, it's not going to be because another duplicate question was added.

Comment: Well the main problem with the older post is that, in my case at least, it is much broader than mine. Furthermore, if you look at the most upvoted question from the I-can't-count-my-gold-badges-any-more-guy it seems to me that the question has already been "dealt-with". So it looks to me that I'm merely pointing out some forgotten features of the initial problem. But I feel like anybody that sees the newer post would go to the duplicate question and say smthg like "meh, already done". It's been a year, nothing has been done and people still vote "requires editing" unappropriately.

Answer (score 1):

When any question is closed as a duplicate of another, its age should not be the only factor.

I have actually asked a question (not feature request, however) that was clearly a duplicate of an earlier question. I even mentioned it when I first asked.

To my surprise, the OTHER question was closed as a duplicate of mine. Quite *pun*ctually, in fact.

Here is my question: [I've done some [research] and I found a tag that needs to go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081)

And here is the older duplicate: [Burn the [research] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258569)

---

Quality <sub><sup>or the popularity of the pun</sup></sub> should rule our judgement of duplicates, not age.

Fortunately, duplication is the easiest of all close types to reverse in most cases. You just have to convince a gold badge holder that you're right.

Meta questions can sometimes gain enormous momentum in little time, and you may be able to create a question that overwhelms a previous one. So I suggest that you rigorously research things, and write your request in a way that blows the other one out of the water.