# The [jest] tag is used for two different projects

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are currently about 80 questions labeled with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest).

Of these, about 70% are questions about [searchbox-io/Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), an Elasticsearch Java Rest Client. The rest are about [facebook/jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest), a JavaScript Unit Testing framework.

The [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jest/info) only talks about the Elasticsearch Java Rest Client.

What is the best course of action to resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: [jestjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs)  appears to be the tag to be used for the FB variant.

Comment: I'd say bombing the frontpage of the `reactjs` page with revisions that's nothing but tag edits probably wasn't/isn't the best course of action. At least fix other problems in the posts while you're at it.

Comment: You might want to read up on [how burnination requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) are generally handled.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest is much more popular then https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest, and a lot of people use https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jest tag for questions about Facebook's jest. So I think that some new tag (like jest-java) should be created for Elasticsearch Java Rest Client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

April 2019 update: Facebook's Jest became popular and is basically known by many as just Jest, while searchbox.io's Jest did not grow as fast. As a conscequence, there are now:

- 5474 [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) questions
- 955 [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) questions
- 69 [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions

which means that:

- **Around 14%** of questions about [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) are incorrectly tagged [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest)
- **Around only 7%** of [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) are actually about searchbox.io's Jest!

---

This is ugly, but there are a few things we can do:

- Edit [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) to [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs): 10s per edit + 5 users with rep > 2k = only half an hour to clean the whole mess. I've already started it using following edit summary: `Corrected a frequent tag misuse: 'jest' (Java Elasticsearch client) replaced by 'jestjs' (JS testing framework)`
- Emphasize the *this-is-not-jestjs* warning in the tag wiki excerpt of [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) so as to prevent future mistakes. A proposition: `DO NOT USE FOR THE JAVASCRIPT TESTING FRAMEWORK, USE [jestjs] INSTEAD. Jest is a Java HTTP Rest client for ElasticSearch.`. This is not ideal as it would only address part of the mistakes, and [tag disclaimers have been criticized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366760/burninate-the-pod-bay-doors-please-trogdor/381815#381815).

Comment: er I'd rather jest be used for the testing framework, rather than force everyone forever to use the other tag. if there is more use of jest as the testing framework, that's what it should represent.

Comment: I like the Debian method. If two projects share a name, neither have it.

Comment: @Braiam where is it documented? I need a source to answer another meta question

Comment: I think [jest] should simply disappear and have two tags: [jest-java] and [jestjs]. I've been suggesting some edits recently to change these tags and several of them (wrong) can't be edited because the title or the content of the questions are unacceptable. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763369/error-with-react-jest-and-enzyme-setup

Answer (score 2):

The jest testing framework seems to be much more popular. The java thing should get the searchbox-jest or something, not the other way around.

That would be less work, and actually help more humans.