# Replace the `jest` tag with `jest-java`

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Recently, I have been reviewing a lot of suggested edits with the following message

> Replacing misleading tag jest (java http rest client) with jestjs (javascript testing framework)

As is obvious, the edit replaces the `jest` tag with `jestjs`

But considering the closeness of these tags, the probability of `jestjs` users using the `jest` tag is high, so maybe we should replace it with `jest-java` to remove ambiguity?

Comment: Related, if not dupe: [The \[jest\] tag is used for two different projects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325738/215552).