# Wrong usage of tag [nx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The section help of the official docs of [nrwl nx](https://nx.dev/) link to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular+nx) with the tags [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx).

The tag description of [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) however states:

> NoMachine NX is a remote access, hosted virtual desktop application.

---

Since there is only a total of 51 questions tagged with [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) I'd retag the nrwl ones myself and also contact the nrwl maintainers about the SO link.

However, I'm not sure what the better alternative is:

1. Reuse the existing tag [nrwl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl)

   - nrwl has other projects as well though, like [angular-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-console)
   - People will probably continue using [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) wrongly
2. Introduce new tag [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx)

   - Would have big overlap with [nrwl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl)
   - Might reduce wrong usage of [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx)
3. Split [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) into [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) and [nomachine-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomachine-nx) (suggestion by Wai Ha Lee)

What do you think?

Comment: What about: 3. Create two new tags, say [tag:nrwl-nx] and [tag:nomachine-nx]. Destroy the [tag:nx] and [tag:nrwl] tags.

Comment: (and contact the site maintainers, linking to this question)

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thanks for the suggestion, I've added it as an alternative. As I stated in the text, I'll contact the maintainers when a solution is found. :-)

Comment: I don't see how "NoMachine NX is a remote access, hosted virtual desktop application." is at all on-topic here, specially with questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222724/how-to-use-h-264-encoding-for-nomachine-on-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091637/x2go-resolution-from-windows-client

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto those certainly seems more suited for Unix&Linux or Superuser

Comment: Related tag misuse: [tag:jest] vs [tag:jestjs] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325738/the-jest-tag-is-used-for-two-different-projects

Comment: I think contacting the site maintainers is best left to SO staff. They can tell exactly what kind of interaction with them and their customers we want and what we can facilitate under which conditions.

Comment: I think it might be enough to make them aware of this thread: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/4694994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion has clearly shown that option 3 is preferred. Hence, I have opened a corresponding [retag-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382809/4694994).