# Split [nx] into [nrwl-nx] and [nomachine-nx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) is ambiguous. It is used for NoMachine NX (virtual desktop application) and nrwl nx (Angular monorepo library).

The [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382559/4694994) clearly favored the solution to split [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) into [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) and [nomachine-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomachine-nx).

Afterwards, it should be considered to retag [nrwl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl) to [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx).

Comment: Before creating a new [tag:nomachine-nx] tag, it should be determined whether that is even on topic

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Good point. How do we proceed with this?

Comment: Well, the tag seems to fit the burnination criteria as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Perhaps create a burnination request, wait for the decision and then post this retag request?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you want to post the burnination request? You've already picked out relevant questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot to consider here, just apart from those two tags, that you mention:

- No Machine NX (Most of the old 34 questions)
- Nrwl NX (The latest 8 questions)

There are also questions related to:

- Siemens NX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_NX) where we need to use [siemens-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/siemens-nx) - 5 of them
- The python package NetworkX where we need to use [networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networkx) - 1
- ARM XN Instruction (why were these tagged with NX?) - 1

It seems like [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) is being used overwhelmingly for NoMachine NX, and not nrwl-nx. I retagged these 8 questions with [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx), as decided.

That said, JS libraries are scary, and I'd rather walk on fire. We've already have enough mess with angular, babel, jest and so on, which has given me enough nightmares. So I just renamed [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) into [nomachine-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomachine-nx).