# Remove [nx] synonym from [nomachine-nx]

Tags: support, synonym-request

When the [nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nx) tag was split into the [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) and [nomachine-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomachine-nx) tags, it was noted that the vast majority of the questions were NoMachine NX questions. [It seems like nx is being used overwhelmingly for NoMachine NX, and not nrwl-nx](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384432/4711754).

However, of the 206 under a newest [nomachine-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomachine-nx) search, under 70 are true NoMachine NX questions.

There are 704 newest [nrwl-nx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nrwl-nx) questions.

I'm more convinced of the need for tag to be removed. What is the process for correcting tags once synonym removed? I.e. can I just do it?

Comment: It would be preferable for you to wait for community consensus before proceeding with any [mass-edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258424/215552).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. Here is my experience:

Tried to tag question `[nx]`. That got automatically translated to `[nomachine-nx]`, and I didn't see any other alternatives, so I assumed it was right. (`nrwl-nx` doesn't show up in the first 6 tags when you type `nx`).

I then happened to get curious and looked a bit closer, and realised that NoMachine seems to be some completely different technology.

I still couldn't find a relevant tag, so I came here to report the issue, and then finally discovered the right tag.

Definitely `nx` should not be a synonym for `nomachine-nx`.