# Should [unminify] be burninated?

Tags: discussion

[unminify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unminify) has 20 questions and 0 followers. All 20 of these questions have at least one other tag, and some have a multitude of tags. It is a good keyword for finding like questions, but that keyword is likely to be in the text of the Q/A anyway.

Should this tag be tossed in the lake of fire?

Comment: Please change the title to this: `Should we stop [unminify]ing this tag?`

Comment: *"It is a good keyword for finding like questions"* ... so what is the problem?

Comment: @Bart It's just noise. Because the rest of the Q/A Makes it clear that a desire to unminify some code is at the heart of the question, and no-one is following the tag, it adds nothing to the question.

Comment: We want people to find those 20 questions so they don't ask them again.  That nobody volunteered to help a questioner debug minified code is not in any way remarkable.

Comment: @dorukayhan If you are unsatisfied with the title, you have the ability to suggest an edit to it by clicking the "edit" link right below the _discussion_ tag

Comment: @TecBrat - No they don't, it's greyed out unless you have 2K+ rep. (Not that I think you *should* change it, this is just a discussion not an actual burnination request.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tag being noise is not a valid reason to remove a tag from the system.

Unminify-ing is a thing developers encounter and you can be an expert in it.

I see no reasons to remove that tag. The questions are on-topic and don't attract much crap, except the few tool-requests. Those should be close voted. The tag can stay.

Comment: And thus I, and anyone reading this meta Q/A, have learned more about what should and shouldn't trigger a tag burn request. See also: [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)