# Should [datetime] and [date] be used together in questions that are about handling datetimes?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, quality-improvement

Recently I was searching for unanswered questions that miss the [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) or the [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) tags and found that some of those questions are about handling datetimes. Then I searched for questions having both tags, doesn't have the [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) but include "date".

I realized that the core of many of those questions are misconceptions, including confusing **date** with **datetimes**<sup>1</sup>. IMHO users of Google Sheets and Google Apps Scripts use the term "date" when they are talking about datetimes, like when are comparing a cell value with a [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

So besides including a brief explanation and the related references, should we add the [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) and [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) or just one of them?

<sup>1</sup>: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/date/info

---

**Examples**

The following examples were found by navigating [[google-apps-script] [google-spreadsheet] -[date] date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20%5Bgoogle-spreadsheet%5D%20-%5Bdate%5D%20date) and related questions:

- [Add a timestamp programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625626/fix-date-and-time)
- [Utilities.formatDate displaying wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377996/utilities-formatdate-displaying-wrong-date)
- [How to get the current time in Google spreadsheet using script editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182020/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-editor)
- [Format a Google Sheets cell in plaintext via Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758913/format-a-google-sheets-cell-in-plaintext-via-apps-script)

Comment: The first thing you can do is update that title. "Fix Date and Time" is a meaningless title, that has very little to do with the actual question. Something more like "Automatically fill in the current date and time in a Google Spreadsheet" would be much more likely to be found in a search.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Thanks for the suggestion. I will wait for answers regarding the tasks before continue editing questions of the search included in the examples section.

Comment: Meh, I see no value in adding those tags to those questions...

Comment: While datetime is a precise c# type to me, date alone represents more the conceptual way of how dates should be manipulated. If you are having troubles with how to use a datetime functionnality, to me it is different then not knowing what is the best way to accomplish a task concerning dates.

Comment: @Antoine: I agree that comparing date to datetime is like comparing text with string. Unfortunately in the spreadsheet argot the terms date and text are used as datetime and string.

Comment: @Rubén how annoying ! sorry for my last comment !

Comment: @Antoine: No problem at all. I appreciate your comment as it help me to learn about other point of views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their wikis

- [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) is about data types and related stuff in a specific application/programming language that represent dates and/or times. E.g. there's a standard Python module with this name.
- while [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date)'s description is rather vague. It seems to refer to handling dates, separate from any specific representation. People seem to be using it for inputting and outputting dates, getting information about a specific date. But also for types and other entities with this name, e.g. in SQL, Javascript and Java.

Both tags prove to have different meanings depending on context, with quite a bit of intersection. [Whether this is tolerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) is a matter for another question.

---

Regarding your specific concern: *with current meanings,* both these tags on the same question are almost always useless. For each specific language/environment, either one or the other seems more appropriate; if both date and datetime types are being talked about, [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

In general, avoid to apply [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) and [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime).

## Extended answer

Thanks for the comments and responses.

Now I think that [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) tag looks more like a "disambiguation tag" than a good tag for the questions that I remember to find on this site with [google-spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) and/or [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). By the other hand, I recently found the [datetime-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-format) that could be more appropriate for some of the example questions and others than the tags mentioned in the question.