# Tags [conv-neural-network] and [convolutional-neural-network] serve the same purpose

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [conv-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) and [convolutional-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-network) serve the same purpose. Former is older than later. Can we retag/burninate/synonymize them?

Comment: The latter, [convolutional-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/convolutional-neural-network/info), has just 16 questions, and no tag wiki. One person with full editing privs could knock this out in no time. What justifies this request?

Comment: Hey, I didn't get what you meant to say. Do you mean I have the privileges to burninate ` convolutional-neural-network ` tag? (Edited the post)

Comment: In a situation like this, all you'd need to do is edit out one tag in favor of the other. It's just 16 questions... and I'm done already, just took minutes. With sufficient privs, none of the edits go to any review queue, so they happen quickly. The now-empty tag will be automatically deleted - at midnight UTC, I want to say, but would have to check.

Comment: For larger or possibly contentious changes, getting community buy-in would be helpful. In my experience with similar tags, it will take vigilance to ensure the "other" tag doesn't get resurrected. That's where a synonym would have been good. If it was a high-traffic PITA issue, you could request a synonym, but again, that's not justifiable for a low traffic tag. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! This was my first encounter with handling duplicate tags.

Comment: @Mogsdad the script runs at  03:00 UTC

Comment: @Mogsdad I think the question is, when do you simply edit all questions to remove the tags, and when do you post a burnination request. Our resources, like [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/1016716), don't mention numbers of posts. If there are hard and fast rules about how many posts must exist before you can no longer edit all of them, I haven't found them.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah, there aren't so much "Rules", as "Guidelines". (Best read with a pirate accent!) It's a qualitative judgement call involving level of effort, return on investment, and disruption to the community (which is mainly "bumps" and negative feelings wrt closed / deleted posts).

Comment: @Mogsdad The other problem is the increase in Suggested Edit reviews when someone (like the OP) with less than 2k rep decides to edit the tag out of questions...

Comment: Related synonyms: [tag:recurrent-neural-network] and [tag:rnn]: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recurrent-neural-network/synonyms

Comment: I came across this thread as I was going to suggest the "synonymization" of these 2 tags. Four months after the original post, [tag:conv-neural-network] has now 2,493 questions; and [tag:convolutional-neural-network] has 324. It seems the latter got "resurrected". I believe it makes sense to synonymize them.