# I believe that the tags [angular5] and [angular6] should not exist

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The problem with those tags is that many times the questions do not have the tag [angular] in addition to it.

I am interested in Angular and I want to know if it is more popular than ReactJS and AngularJS.

We do not add the version number to other tags like [python2] and [python3], usually we just call it [python], same thing with almost everything else.

Also the differences between [angular5] and [angular6] are sometimes very very very small like just bug fixes.

Angular6 also has Material but that is a separate tag [angular-material].

Same thing applies to [angular2-forms] should not exist, it should be only [angular-forms] and that tag is good for versions 2, 4, 5, 6 and so on.

Again, this applies to ALL ALL ALL the angular tags that have a version number.

Comment: I am going to give you more context about these tags. Angular version 1 is called [angularjs] and it is very different than the version 2 of Angular which was a complete rewrite and not compatible at all. so the tags [angular2] and [angular3] and [angular4] got merged into [angular] but people continued to create more tags like [angular5] and [angular6] and if every release or version was an entire new framework, which is not accurate, they are all [angular].

Comment: There is no place on earth where people downvote so hart like in meta. Disgusting! I feel like OP has a point here. At least its fair for discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags [angular2] and [angular4] were merged into one single tag [angular].

We should do the same to the tags [angular5] and [angular6] to have an accurate count on questions about Angular.

Python 2 and Python3 are not backwards compatible, but Angular 5 and 6 yes they are. The differences between angular versions are sometimes just bug fixes and new functionality but not worth an entire new tag and count.

We don't have a tag [reactjs15] and a tag [reactjs16] because that level of granularity is not helping anybody really and it does hurts the count. 
Source: http://reactjs.org/blog/2018/08/01/react-v-16-4-2.html

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR There does not seem to be a reason or need to merge these tags with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) at this time.** There are often good reasons to have different tags for different versions. As long as it is clear that a significant number of questions pertain specifically to one version, as opposed to any other, there should be a tag specific to that version.

## Some Background

We often do use version numbers for certain technologies, especially when the differences involve major (especially breaking) changes. For example, you wrote:

> We do not add the version number to other tags like [python2] and [python3], usually we just call it [python], same thing with almost everything else.

This is not really accurate. While we use [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (~1.0 MM questions), we also use [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (~117k questions), [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) (~85k questions) and a number of other, version-specific tags for Python. Why? Because Python 2.x and 3.x are very different animals, much like Angular and AngularJS.

## The Angular Tags

The short description for the [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) tag reads:

> Questions about **Angular version 5**, the web framework from Google. **Use this tag for Angular questions which are specific to only version 5.** Use tag Angular for any Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version.

(emphasis added). The [angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6) tag is similar:

> Questions about **Angular version 6**, the web framework from Google. **Use this tag for Angular questions which are specific to only version 6.** Use tag Angular for any Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version.

From time to time, people are going to have questions that pertain only to version 5 or only to version 6. In that case, they *should* use one of these tags. And, for that matter, those tags should continue to exist unless and until the community determines that essentially none of the 5,867 questions tagged [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) and essentially none of the 2,484 questions tagged [angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6) are truly version-specific.

## When Tag Burnination Is Appropriate

There are two canonical posts relevant to your question:

- [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/2057919)
- [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/2057919)

As the first of these posts explains,

> ## Criteria for Burnination
>
> [There are four criteria to consider for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):
>
> > 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> > 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> > 3. Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?
> > 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
> >
> > [ . . . ]
>
> A tag must **fail *all* of these tests** in order to be considered for burnination. **If it is clear that removing the tag will do more harm than good**, then we should obviously not remove it.

The [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) and [angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6) tags, as far as I can tell, do not fail *any* of those criteria, much less all of them.

## Conclusion

I don't think you've really demonstrated that these tags are candidates for burnination using the established criteria. Unless and until the community determines - separately for each of the tags at issue - that the tags satisfy the burnination criteria, they should be left alone. Removing them without a thorough review of the affected questions would result in information loss and therefore be destructive to the site.

Comment: I think that it would be helpful if every time someone uses the tag [angular5] then the tag [angular] automatically gets added. so it is easier to count how many questions about angular were asked this month. and the same would apply to [rypescript2.0] and [typescript]

Comment: There’s no reason you can’t perform such searches on your own; it’s not like it’s difficult to find all tags relevant to Angular and perform one master search. Also note that doing that for these tags wouldn’t address all of the other Angular tags. Most importantly, what you’re proposing is (1) a major programming change and (2) counter to the guidelines on tags, which are to use the most specific tags applicable to the problem, not to use both a narrow tag and a broader tag.

Comment: but then why don't we have a tag [reactjs15] and a tag [reactjs16] ? source: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/08/01/react-v-16-4-2.html the answer is because that level of granularity is not helping anybody really but it does affect the counts

Comment: Because users of those technologies either don’t feel the need for those tags or haven’t made the case for their creation. There’s not a one-size-fits-all policy that says “do create version-specific tags” or “don’t create version-specific tags.” It’s driven by the (very well-established) criteria I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: This goes as far as affecting recruitment, I have seen recruiters looking for developers with experience  in angular 5, when we are all using 6 now. This was a confusing that started with angularjs and angular2, then got resolved, and someone started it again when they created the tag [angular5].