# Don't make "dnn" a synonym for "dotnetnuke"

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-removal-request

DNN also means "[deep neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning#Deep_neural_networks)". I think that's a very common topic on Stack Overflow, even more common than a specific technology such as "dotnetnuke".

"DNN" isn't a synonym for just "dotnetnuke" and nothing else. It's three letters that mean different things to different people. It certainly doesn't imply "dotnetnuke" in all situations, or even most.

Please undo that. The "DNN" tag is valuable and the existence of this synonym destroys information.

I understand the synonym was created in 2010. Since then, the world has changed a lot... in terms of what "DNN" means. It's time to remove the synonym.

Comment: How does it *destroy information*? And do you also propose that the dnn tag be blacklisted after synonym removal?

Comment: Traversing through this tag, I could find 5 questions mistagged with [dnn]. Not a significant bunch, but it may happen that someone else had already done their part re-tagging them.

Comment: I'm not talking about mistags. I'm saying "dnn" does **not** **only** mean "dotnetnuke" in 2021. I propose that the "dnn" tag be a regular usable tag again. dotnetnuke has the "dotnetnuke" tag, which is unambiguous. "dnn" is ambiguous in that it can mean Deep Neural Networks, so it **should not** be a synonym of "dotnetnuke". I don't want people typing the tag "dnn" and arrive at "dotnetnuke" accidentally. I want the tag to *not* be a synonym of "dotnetnuke". I hope that's clear now.

Comment: Umm, I don't think "dnn" tag is useful enough to exist, considering how it can be ambiguous. I guess I'd prefer to unsynonymize the tag and create a new [tag:deep-neural-networks] tag if it worths.

Comment: sounds good. there's "conv-neural-network", "convolutional-neural-network" (already a synonym? still listed separately), and "recurrent-neural-network" already, so perhaps the singular form should be used to continue the pattern. I can't give an opinion on any "blacklisting"; I don't know what consequences that would have.

Comment: People asking questions of those sort will typically just use [tag:deep-learning]. But note that not all questions about deep learning are on-topic here, and this one is known to attract some questions not worth keeping.

Comment: I consider DNNs to be implementation (and deep learning to be an academic field, not implementation). I grant you those kinds of questions should also be tagged with the specific framework, unless someone wrote their own neural network inference (which is feasible and not unheard of!)

Comment: you sound offended. I don't know you and nothing I said was meant to offend. I don't have an opinion on letting it "roam free" or "blacklisting" it (I didn't even know that was an option!). is that clear now?

Comment: OK, to clarify, going through the steps of tag burnination and the topics which make it a candidate for removal ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)) would contribute to asserting an opinion. The rest is tangential, so I removed my other comment.

Comment: and as a note to myself and anyone else who isn't versed in this realm: an explanation of the distinctions of removing a tag and blacklisting it https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120642/1033513

Comment: *common topic* i doubt that very much

Comment: DNN is [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNN_(software)) the ***new name*** for  DotNetNuke.

Comment: and YES, people go through that tag and fix mistags. not finding "enough" mistags must not be construed as them not happening or not being an issue.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not in favor of bringing back a vaguer tag for this. We have a [neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-network) tag, but no "deep" variant (Google thinks [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) is the same thing, however).

The real issue is should we have such a tag on SO? Several more specific stacks may be better suited

- [Artificial Intelligence has such a tag already](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-neural-networks) (they have no "DNN" entries either)
- Data Science [has a deep-learning tag](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning)
- [Computer Science has a neural-networks tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks)

I would say we can make do with [neural-networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks) and [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning). If we need anything to make "dnn" show up, we can always make a synonym like, say, [dnn-neural-network] and point it to [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning). But, as Peter Mortensen noted, [DNN is the official name of DotNetNuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNN_(software)). Removing the synonym makes no sense.

I went ahead and added [dnn-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnn-learning) and [deep-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-neural-network) as synonyms to [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) after I merged [dnn-module] with [dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke). There were a few misuses there of DNN for this, which pushed me to do that. This is what users trying to add DNN tags will see, which should clear up any confusion about what tag to use

[image: DNN]

Comment: Very nice maneuver.

Comment: it appears to me that someone reestablished "dnn" as an alias for "dotnetnuke". people AGAIN tag their neural network questions as "dnn", which gets interpreted as "dotnetnuke". I see a change to the synonym that is about 3 hours old.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm not sure why it shows "last renamed" as yesterday. The synonym owner hasn't changed, nor its creation date. I think we've reached the most we can do here for clarity. It eventually has to fall to the users to pay attention to what they tag. FWIW we still get off-topic SEO questions for the same reason.

Answer (score -15):

I disagree the decline of this suggestion for the following reasons:

1. If a tag has essentially different meanings, the correct solution is to forbid its usage and explaining in the tag excerpt, which tags to use instead. Roughly this: "Tag forbidden. Use [dot-net-nuke] or [deep-neural-network]".
2. Saying for any computer science, electronics, or any science thing that it is off-topic, actually decreases the quality of the site. Programming is more than the lexical knowledge of various languages and frameworks. Borderline topics (like in our case, deep neural networks) should be on-topic on all the sites (*[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour)* and Stack Overflow), and not forbidden on all of them.

Comment: The tag has one meaning: DotNetNuke, which is the old name for the product now named DNN. The fact that those three letters could also refer to deep neural networks (questions about which *remain perfectly on topic where they intersect with the topicality of Stack Overflow* [i.e., is a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development]) is not a reason for the *tag* not to refer to a specific product. As Machavity has shown in his answer, the UX shows both tags.

Comment: `the correct solution is to forbid its usage and explaining in the tag excerpt` In a perfect world, maybe. You know how many tags we've burninated because they were misused? People do not read excerpts. If a tag even looks like something they want to tag it as, they'll tag it. Removing the option to misuse the tag is the only way.

Comment: @Machavity If the usage of the tag is forbidden, it can not be used. If it can not be used, it can not be misused.

Comment: That only works with blacklisted tags. Putting "don't use this tag" in the usage doesn't actually stop anyone from using the tag.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, then blacklisted. Thanks the insight. Not if it would matter. The general behavior of the system (people + rules) clearly shows that doing things well is the last in the list.

Comment: Except DNN is the name of the project and has been since 2013.